# Play Minecraft on Wii U with other player on PC

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, wii-u

Is it possible to play Minecraft on Wii U with other players playing on a PC? Even if I set the game as "online" on Wii U, it doesn't appear on local multiplayer list on my PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  They are not compatible, they don't even have all the same blocks.

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot do so.** As far as it goes in terms of features and architecture, Minecraft and Minecraft: Wii U Edition are not the same game and cannot be used in conjunction with another. Cross-platform multiplayer in this way does not work.

Answer (score -2):

Only players using the same system as you can join you on public games. For example, someone playing on a PS4 can play with other players playing on a PS4, but they can't play with someone on an Xbox. Same with a PC. Only players playing on a PC can play with other players on a PC, but they can't play with players on a Wii U.